# Unable to start Spring Roo and get it working

Tags: windows-7

I'm unable to start Spring Roo. It doesn't start from cmd line as well as from STS. When I create "Spring Roo Project" then Roo Shell doesn't pop up and there is error mark on the project.

- OS: Windows 7 64bit
- JDK: 1.6.0_25 also 64bit

I've last version of STS but same problems occurred with 2.7.1 Roo version is 1.1.5 release.

Here are the [errors from command line start up](http://pastebin.com/mE0sYrnb).

First 20 lines from that error block:

```
__ERROR: Error starting file:/D:/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.backup-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
(org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.backup [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor.event)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 39.0: missing requirement [39.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.ant)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]])

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.backup [7]: 
Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] package; 
(&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor.event)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 39.0: missing requirement [39.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.ant)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3409)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1719)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

ERROR: Error starting file:/D:/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
(org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 36.0: missing requirement [36.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 39.0: missing requirement [39.0] package; (&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.ant)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package; (package=javax.xml.namespace)]]])

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: 
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.springframework.roo.addon.configurable [8]: Unable to resolve 8.0: missing requirement [8.0] package;
(&(package=org.springframework.roo.classpath)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 36.0: missing requirement [36.0] package;
(&(package=org.springframework.roo.file.monitor)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 39.0: missing requirement [39.0] package;
(&(package=org.springframework.roo.support.ant)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 52.0: missing requirement [52.0] package;
(package=javax.xml.namespace)]]]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3409)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1719)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1148)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)__
```

I have tried running .bat file from roo's bin folder as the administrator but it's the same problem.

I've followed Installation guides and basically only path variable to roo\bin is needed - didn't help much.

Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is kind of solved but not really.

Firstly what didn't help:

- turning firewall off
- turning antivirus off
- turning both from above off

I know that the reason of the problem is installation localization different than main partition. I've installed once more full STS (sts + maven + roo + server) but this time on C drive so on my main partition. Surprisingly it worked. It seems like folders get some more rights when I did install it on main partition. Still I don't know how to add these permissions simply because there are more groups in that permission window and for time being I don't know how to add these on the other drive. Also permissions inside those groups which cover are different. The two missing groups are: TrustedInstaller, CREATOR-OWNER (I might translated wrong the second one as I don't use English version of windows. Still it's caps locked)

**Long story short:** Install it on your main drive. Else you have to fix permissions somehow.